Using await but the function returns right away
I have a function that I am trying to call which has below signature
  public async submit(
    value: string,
    callbackFn: (response: string[]) => never | void
  ): Promise<void>

I understand that this function returns a promise of void, but one of the values of the signature is a callback that contains the response in it.
I am calling that function like this
export const getResponse = async (
  service: Service,
  input: string
): Promise<string[]> => {
  try {
    const result = await service.submit(
      input,
      (response) => {
        return response;
      }
    );

    return Promise.resolve(result as string[]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
};

When debugging, I realized that even with setting await service.submit(...) the code execution continues and the caller to export const getResponse receives undefined value.
Is there a way I can force the code to not return until there is a response from the callback?

public async submit(
  value: string,
  callbackFn: (response: string[]) => void
): Promise<string[]> {
  return new Promise<string[]>((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      try {
        const response = [value, "response"];
        callbackFn(response);
        resolve(response); 
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error); 
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}

// Define the getResponse function
export const getResponse = async (
  service: Service,
  input: string
): Promise<string[]> => {
  try {
    const result = await service.submit(
      input,
      (response) => {
        console.log("Callback response:", response);
      }
    );

    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
};


The problem I see with this proposal is that you are changing the implementation of public async submit, but I can't. That is a given function that I need to work with as is.
